# Can ActionScript Workers be used to play / generate Sounds in a separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash, audio, worker

I'm very new to **ActionScript Workers**, but I would like to know if this is possible.

From what I have read, **ActionScript Workers** (ASW) are like separate threads that can do more CPU intensive calculations without interrupting the Main thread (which is executing your main SWF file).

The only example I really seen kicking around was the one illustrating animation playing at a consistent rate while an ASW took care of loading or calculating some intensive math formulas.

Is the Sound API available for ActionScriptWorkers?

Comment: ActionScript workers are scheduled for release soon after Flash Player 11.3 / AIR 3.3 - they are not currently available.

Comment: @JasonSturges and OPer awesome this is why I use StackOverflow, I somehow completely missed this announcement and threading is something I've complained about for so long... so yeah thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: You can try them out with the latest Flash player beta, found [here](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/flashplayer11-4/). But the [release notes](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/shared/air3-4_flashplayer11-4_p2_releasenotes.pdf) say you would ideally need the new beta version of Flash Builder (for debugging).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***(Reposted under my proper login)***

They certainly can! Check out my recent blog post on exactly this:

http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/multi-threaded-sound-synthesis-in-flex.html#!/2012/09/multi-threaded-sound-synthesis-in-flex.html

After a fair bit of tinkering, I actually generate a byte array in a background worker and then write the data back to the SampleDataEvent's data property in the primordial thread (i.e. the user interface).

I write the data from the worker from the previous SampleDataEvent while the worker generates the data for the next one - so FlashPlayer is actually doing three tasks simultaneously: offering a responsive UI, playing a tone and generating the next tone.

simon

Comment: Very interesting. I found a glitch with deleting nodes in your example (seems like playing nodes are not properly disposed, the sound continues). It seems like there is still that annoying "lag" between clicking and hearing the sound, is that something that can be adjusted? Also, sometimes there's a clipping sound when the sound begins. Is that a synchronization issue with the way you've aligned the waveforms to the bytearray maybe?

Comment: Hi bigp, my code isn't going to win any awards I'm afraid, some of it is quite ancient and I cobbled in the worker stuff while eating my dinner over the last few evenings :)

I was going to spend some time doing some particle and physics stuff in my next free time, so my sound synthesis stuff may get ignored for a while. Feel free to download the code and improving it though.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to venture out onto a cliff and answer YES to this question.

The [release notes](http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/shared/air3-4_flashplayer11-4_p2_releasenotes.pdf) has a list of "non-functional" API's, I don't see any sound related classes in the list.

> The following APIs will not be available from within a background
>   worker. Any attempt to construct an instance of any of these will
>   throw an IllegalOperationError with the message "This feature is not
>   available within this context," the errorID will be the same in all
>   instances, allowing developers to key off of this value.

- `flash.desktop.Clipboard` // calling constructor will throw; calling generalClipboard will return null
- `flash.desktop.NativeDragManager` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.desktop.Updater` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.display.NativeMenu` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.display.NativeWindow` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.display.ToastWindow` // can't access instance because stage.window will never be defined
- `flash.display.Window` // can't access instance because stage.window will never be defined
- `flash.external.ExtensionContext` // createExtensionContext() will always return null or throw an error
- `flash.external.ExternalInterface` // available returns false
- `flash.html.*` // HTMLLoader.isSupported returns false
- `flash.media.CameraRoll` // supportsAddBitmapData and supportsBrowseForImage returns false
- `flash.media.CameraUI` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.media.StageWebView` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.net.drm.*` // DRMManager.isSupported returns false
- `flash.printing.*` // PrintJob.isSupported returns false
- `flash.security.XMLSignatureValidator` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.system.IME` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.system.SystemUpdater` // calling constructor throws
- `flash.text.StageText` // calling constructor throws flash.ui.ContextMenu // isSupported returns false
- `flash.ui.GameInput` // isSupported returns false
- `flash.ui.Mouse` // all methods are no-ops; setting 'cursor' property is a no-op

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this means each ActionScriptWorkers could play 32 SoundChannels each? lol, that's worth a try!