# Can AS3 Workers Manipulate the Stage?

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash, worker

AS3 Worker Documentation states:

> "The primordial worker is the worker in which the initial swf is
>   running. This worker controls the rendering to the screen."

Does this mean that actionscript that renders to the screen in a worker will be passed to the primordial worker?

Or can I not render the screen in a worker?

Basically, my flash application loads a child SWF that executes to the screen while the main SWF continues running in the background, doing some processing.

Am I able to run the child SWF as a worker, and therefore on a second thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in similar threads:
[Can ActionScript Workers be used to play / generate Sounds in a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902863/can-actionscript-workers-be-used-to-play-generate-sounds-in-a-separate-thread?rq=1)

[Can there be multiple rendering worker threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244958/can-there-be-multiple-rendering-worker-threads?rq=1)

I guess this can be marked as duplicate. Thanks for reading everyone!

**The child SWF won't work running as a worker.**